# What the sql query can generate 100,000 mysql rows with random data?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have table with 12 columns, How by sql query i can insert 100 random symbol in each column of row to generate 100 000 rows

Comment: Please edit your question with more detail, such as data that you want to insert and what you mean by random symbol and how you turn 100 random symbols into 100,000 rows.

Comment: i need 100,000 rows with 12 columns of random data with length of 100 characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a procedure to achieve this task:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertRandomRows(IN NumRows INT)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE i INT;
        SET i = 1;
        START TRANSACTION;
        WHILE i <= NumRows DO
            INSERT INTO table_name (status, tel_mobile, tel_home, age,
                call_time, created_at, fio, address, comment) VALUES (
                ROUND(RAND() * 1000000),
                ROUND(RAND() * 1000000),
                ROUND(RAND() * 1000000),
                ROUND(RAND() * 1000000),
                ROUND(RAND() * 1000000),
                ROUND(RAND() * 1000000),
                LEFT(CONCAT(
                    MD5( CAST( RAND() AS CHAR )),
                    MD5( CAST( RAND() AS CHAR )),
                    MD5( CAST( RAND() AS CHAR )),
                    MD5( CAST( RAND() AS CHAR ))
                ), 100),
                LEFT(CONCAT(
                    MD5( CAST( RAND() AS CHAR )),
                    MD5( CAST( RAND() AS CHAR )),
                    MD5( CAST( RAND() AS CHAR )),
                    MD5( CAST( RAND() AS CHAR ))
                ), 100),
                LEFT(CONCAT(
                    MD5( CAST( RAND() AS CHAR )),
                    MD5( CAST( RAND() AS CHAR )),
                    MD5( CAST( RAND() AS CHAR )),
                    MD5( CAST( RAND() AS CHAR ))
                ), 100)
            );
            SET i = i + 1;
        END WHILE;
        COMMIT;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;


CALL InsertRandomRows(100000);
```

For text fields I used "MD5" function to create a random 32 char long string, concatenate 4 of them (32 x 4 = 128 chars) and truncate first 100 characters.

For integer fields you can use RAND directly to generate random numbers.

Hope it helps!

***Edit: Sorry, I had a mistake, LEFT function parameters was swapped.***

Comment: error #1304 - PROCEDURE InsertRandomRows already exists Y_Y

Comment: Probably you typed the procedure code twice. You only need to type it once. Then you can repeat as many times as needed "CALL InsertRandomRows(100000);" or "CALL InsertRandomRows(500000);" or as many rows as you want to insert. If you need to edit the procedure you can do it using a frontend (like phpmyadmin) or deleting it before recreating it again with modified code using "DROP PROCEDURE InsertRandomRows".

Comment: instead of `int_field, string_field` i need write my columns? If yes - i got #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1. If i change only `table_name` - #1054 - Unknown column 'int_field' in 'field list'

Comment: You need to repeat "LEFT" block for every text field. If you give me your table definition using "SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name;" I'll code the exact procedure.

Comment: my columns: id int auto_increment; status int; fio varchar; address varchar; tel_mobile int; tel_home int; age int; call_time int; comment text; created_at int

Comment: Done! Please, try it. If still throwing an error I needed exact table definition to reproduce beaviour in my test environment with `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name`. Remember: you must adjust your table name! (I don't know what name is).